# CLI include paths to run zend framework via cron

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, set-include-path

I wrote a command line utility using Zend Framework to do some nightly reporting. It uses a ton of the same functionality the accompanying site. It works great when I run it by hand, but when I run it on cron I have include path issues. Seems like it should be easily fixed with set_include_path, but maybe I'm missing something?

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/clientname/
    application
        Globals.php
    commandline
        commandline_bootstrap.php       
    public_html
        public_bootstrap.php        
    library
        Zend
```

In public_bootstrap.php I use set_include_path without a problem, relative to the current directory:

```
set_include_path('../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

If I understand correctly, in commandline_bootstrap.php I need to put in the absolute path, so cron knows where everything is. My file starts like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_include_path('/var/www/clientname/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());  
require_once "../application/Globals.php";
```

But when I run it via cron I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once():
>   Failed opening required
>   '../application/Globals.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/clientname/library/')
>   in
>   /var/www/clientname/commandline/zfcli.php
>   on line 11

I think PHP is accepting my new path, because when I run it command line and dump the phpinfo I can see:

> include_path =>
>   /var/www/clientname/library/:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
>   => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

I admit the syntax here looks a little strange, but I can’t figure out how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
summer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Pádraic's approach to `zf-cli` at [ZFPlanet](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet/blob/master/scripts/zf-cli).

Here is a little shell script I use to execute php file from the shell, so I'm sure what the cwd is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
include('doctrine-cli.php');
```

There was also [a bug in the autoloader's `isReadable()`](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9263) prior to 1.10.4, try upgrading.

Comment: thanks, the trick I ended up using was very similar to the ZFPlanet sample you posted. I think the key was the use of:

realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application')

everything is now working as planned :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the current directory of the CRON job is not the `commandline` directory. Use `getcwd()` to check the current directory.

*[Edit:]*

Also do not use relative paths in `set_include_path` as this may result in unexpected behaviour - except of course for the current directory `.` . You can use `realpath()` to get the the absolute path, before you add it to the `include_path`.

Comment: correct, I have cron running as me, so it runs from my home directory, /home/summer. I also tried a relitive path from my home directory. 
set_include_path('../../var/www/clientname/library/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

Doesn't work. Seams like I should be able to make it absolute from / right?

Comment: Yeah you should not. I just added that to my answer.